# Determine the current Solr current core used for Hybris

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I am currently getting some Solr data I need from a core (found in Core selector drop down/comboBox list)

But every 24 hours, Hybris will take data to render products on site either from flip or flop core.

For instance, if today it gets data from Solr core 'flip', then tomorrow will take data from the 'flop' Solr core, and so on.

[image]

**I want to determine** (from the Java code if possible) **outside of Hybris** (by interrogating a Hybris web service or anything else) **which one of the Solr core is currently used**.

Comment: you can get the info from the logs...

Comment: Are you sure it isn't using an alias as the access point? .. and the flip/flop postfix are just which core to update before switching the aliases around?

Comment: I am querying to the Solr end point directly, and I've chosen one of them and is not correct... No, there is no alias and inside Hybris I think it's taken somehow inside the system and I want to get this info outside of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on SAP forum.

It seems it needs a custom development on Hybris itself then an extra webservice to expose such an info.

The development can be started from a flexible search:

```
  select {solrfacetsearchconfig.name},{solrindex.qualifier}
        from {solrindex join solrfacetsearchconfig 
              on {solrindex.facetsearchconfig}={solrfacetsearchconfig.pk}}
           where {solrindex.active}=true
```

And then expose the result above on a webservice which is accesible from the outside as I need.

The discussion is here:
https://answers.sap.com/questions/12770851/solr-core-which-one-active-flip-or-flop-.html